# While trying to upload image of 50kb size using wcf , shows error 'The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.'

Tags: c#, wcf, file-upload, exception

My server config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HttpEndpointBinding" receiveTimeout="00:10:30" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="524288">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service   name="mobservice.ImobService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="mobservice.ImobService" bindingConfiguration="HttpEndpointBinding" name="BasicHttpBinding_MobileService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true" httpHelpPageUrl="" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="60000000"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My client config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ImobService"  sendTimeout="00:10:30" maxBufferSize="250000000" maxBufferPoolSize="250000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="250000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="4500000" maxStringContentLength="4500000" maxArrayLength="4500000" maxBytesPerRead="40960000" maxNameTableCharCount="250000000" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://anishk.india-powai.orioninc.com/mobservice/MobService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ImobService" contract="MobileService.ImobService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ImobService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Service contract:

```
[OperationContract]
void InsertEmployeeData(EmployeeDetail empName);
```

Method definition:

```
public void InsertEmployeeData(EmployeeDetail empName)
{
    ctx.EmployeeDetails.AddObject(empName);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Call from client:

```
EmployeeDetail data = new EmployeeDetail();
data.EmployeeName = collection.Get("EmployeeName");
data.Designation = collection.Get("Designation");
data.EmailID = collection.Get("EmailID");
data.City = collection.Get("City");
data.State = collection.Get("State");
data.Country = collection.Get("Country");               
data.Photo = ConvertImage(@"E:\Anish\S6M0.png");
conn.InsertEmployeeData(data);
```

while trying to pass EmployeeDetail object with photo as byte array to wcf service gets exception. Image with 6kb gets inserted .but image with size 50 kb throws exception:

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.

But i need to do with image size up to 2 mb.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling debugging in your `web.config` file. This will give you more meaningful error messages than just `(400) Bad Request`.

Add this XML snippet under your `<configuration>` tag:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  <trace enabled="true" localOnly="false"> 
  <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
```

and try again.

Just don't forget to remove the debugging flags once you're done, because they are a [security vulnerability when used in a production environment](http://dotnetstories.wordpress.com/2007/10/13/the-worst-5-mistakes-in-the-webconfig-file/).

Comment: Added the snippet and in excception stack trace i got :-  Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at MvcTest.MobileService.ImobService.InsertEmployeeData(EmployeeDetail empName) at MvcTest.MobileService.ImobServiceClient.InsertEmployeeData(EmployeeDetail empName)